# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tags'

Tags: django, cherrypy, pyinstaller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver2", line 1353, in communicate<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver2", line 868, in respond<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver2", line 2267, in respond<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/cherrypy.wsgiserver.wsgiserver2", line 2477, in __call__<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.core.handlers.wsgi", line 206, in __call__<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.core.handlers.base", line 194, in get_response<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.core.handlers.base", line 229, in handle_uncaught_exception<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.views.debug", line 69, in technical_500_response<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.views.debug", line 322, in get_traceback_html<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.template.base", line 125, in __init__<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.template.base", line 152, in compile_string<br/>
  File "home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.template.debug", line 35, in __init__<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.template.base", line 239, in __init__<br/>
  File "/home/rpmbuild/venv/build/pyi.linux2/MF/out00-PYZ.pyz/django.template.base", line 353, in add_library<br/>

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tags'
```

I have pyinstaller for django project running on cherrypy server.
its working from `python manage.py runserver` from command prompt
not working using bundled through pyinstaller.

I have tested for both development environment and production environment in settings.py

```
DEBUG = False/True<br>
Allowed_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: So the question is `not working using bundled through pyinstaller.` ??

Comment: right..It's not working using bundled through pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you use the code like this:

```
<something>.tags
```

where  is estimated to None

Comment: I have not used like that

Answer (score 0):

If you use `django.contrib.markup.templatetags.markup` so this is the problem, because `django.contrib.markup.templatetags.markup` is depricated

Comment: I have checked throughout , templatetags not been used in  project.

Comment: Maybe other depricated ??